# Normal php login to YII login

Tags: php, database, yii

i have a normal php login which connects to a database authenticates the user, now i need to convert this to a login that uses yii framework, can anybody tell me in order to do so.. what are the first things that i should do and can i convert this to yii login. following is the current login function that i have to call

```
function login($usr,$pwd) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE us.username='$usr' AND us.password='$pwd'; ";
    $dataReader=$command->query();
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($dataReader);
    $log = new stdClass();
    if($row) {
        $pro->accountID = (int)$row['accountID'];
        $pro->accountname = $row['accountname'];
        $pro->usertype = (int)$row['usertype'];
                $string = rand() . 'SURVAYLAND' . rand() . $usr. $pwd;
            $_SESSION['SURVEY_AUTHENTICATE_KEY'] = md5($string);
    } else {
        $pro = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you call `Yii::app()->user`, you get an instance of `CWebUser`. This is the way Yii represents the user that it currently viewing your application.

This user can be logged in or access the app without login (in other words, be a guest).

[Class CWebUser](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#login-detail) has a method called `login`, which, as you expected, logs in a user.

Method `login()` takes as argument an object that implements IUserIdentity interface.

The easiest way to make your own is to create a simple class (call it MyIdentity for exemple):

```
//this class' constructor takes a username and a password
class MyIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $_id;
    public function authenticate()
    {
         // check username and password in DB
         // return true or false to signal whether user should be logged in
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

Then use what you just created to actually log in an user:

```
// Login a user with the provided username and password.
$identity=new MyIdentity($username,$password);
if($identity->authenticate())
    Yii::app()->user->login($identity);
else
    echo $identity->errorMessage;
```